# Is it possible to remove the tooltip and hover effect in the pie high chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, pie-chart

I successfully created the pie chart below.

[image]

I am trying to remove this tooltip and hover effect.

and here It's a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-highcharts-ca5bgg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to what I have done so far.

I tried many fields from [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions).
But not finding any good field to work.

Can anyone suggest how can we achieve this?

**Edited :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in a very simple way, in addition to disabling the tooltip, you also need to disable hover and inactive states.

```
tooltip: {
  enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    states: {
      hover: {
        enabled: false
      },
      inactive: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-highcharts-gdhckk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.enabled 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.states.hover.enabled 
 https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.states.inactive.enabled